# Displaying a specific date

Tags: shell, date

I'm trying to display a specific date in Unix, using the date command, I can't figure out how to display a date other than today's date.

For example, if I was trying to display `July 4, 2011` I use

```
$ date +"%B %d, %Y"
```

But I keep getting today's date in that format. How can I change it so that it displays the date I want?

Answer (score 4):

If you're running Linux:

```
date +"%B %d, %Y" -d 2011-07-04
```

From [`man date`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date):

```
   -d, --date=STRING
          display time described by STRING, not 'now'
```

Comment: The answer largely depends on the particular flavour of UNIX the user32270 is using. For example, the suggested variant will not work on HP-UX or older SunOS, in fact, there's no way to display an arbitrary date by `date` there.

Comment: @Leonid - Either way, this information will be in `man` if it is possible in their environment.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, `date` is not the tool for that (though some implementations, like GNU date can do it as a non-standard extension).

If you want to do date manipulation portably, the best you can do is probably to use `perl` (which is installed on virtually every non-embedded Unix) and its `POSIX` module for the `strftime` and `mktime` functions. There is a plethora of other  friendlier date manipulation modules for `perl` but they would generally not be installed by default, at least not with older versions of `perl`.

```
perl -MPOSIX -le 'print strftime "%B %d, %Y", @ARGV' 0 0 0 4 7 "$((2011 - 1900))"
```